# I need to define a function to input a value then call the function and print it

Tags: python

```
def name_function():
    firstName = input("Enter your first name: ")

name_function()
print("My name is " + firstName)
```

the expected output is the `name`

Comment: Your function `name_function()` reads the name from the user into `firstName` then discards the result (it doesn't return its value). Your code as show should yield an error on the `print` statement since `firstName` isn't defined at that point.

Comment: Yes thank you so much that helps a lot now that I have an example thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def name_function():
    firstName = input("Enter your first name: ")
    return firstName # forgot to add this

firstName = name_function() #forgot to assign value to firstName
print(firstName)
```